# Why is the hosting directory added to the URL on SSL/WWW redirect?

Tags: .htaccess

In my `public_html` directory I have an `htaccess` file that points the primary domain to a subdirectory. The file is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Main Site Point
# ------------------------------

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*\.)?example\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dir/
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dir/$1
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*\.)?example\.
#RewriteRule ^(/)?$ dir/ [L]

</IfModule>
```

Then in the `dir` directory I have an `htaccess` file that controls adding www/ssl, slashes, etc., and it is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Remove Trailing Dot
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]

# Multiple Slashes
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule ^.*$ $0 [L,NE,R=302]

# Trailing Slash
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]

# Force SSL
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Add WWW
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

What's happening is that if I visit `http://example.com`, `https://example.com`, or `http://www.example.com` then they all redirect to `https://www.example.com/dir/`. Through my script I can detect the presence of `dir` and redirect without it, but I'd prefer to not have to do that if possible. Is anyone aware of a fix to this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your .htaccess file from dir folder to public_html folder and change "RewriteBase /" to "RewriteBase /dir/"

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dir/

# Remove Trailing Dot
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]

# Multiple Slashes
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule ^.*$ $0 [L,NE,R=302]

# Trailing Slash
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]

# Force SSL
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Add WWW
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

More info http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase

Comment: This worked! Thank you, JarekBaran. Just to clarify, in case anyone else finds this useful, I put the `Main Site Point` section below the `Add WWW` section in the `htaccess` file that's in the `public_html` directory.